# Swift Core Data saving and updating entities incorrectly

Tags: swift, core-data, updating

I have two custom functions I use in my code for fetching and storing data from an API Service to Core Data entities. However, I am running into some problems with updating values on the Core data entities.

1. When the view loads, it loads data from the API and the store function is called to store an array of entities to Core Data.
2. When the user taps a button, the API loads the same data again but with other filters and thus the save functions is called again.
3. The fetch function is then called as well to load the entities in an array to display in the View.

However, when the data is saved for a second time, it seems that it does not correctly update the already stored entities into CoreData. I have set the Core Data entity to be unique and have set a `viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` such that duplicates are handled when the Core Data environment is saved. Does anyone know how to solve the problem with updating entities in Core Data?

The fetch function is as follows:

```
func fetchCachedUserInformation(leaderboardType: APIRequest) -> Bool {
    
    self.leaderboardResult.removeAll()
    
    print("OPHALEN VAN DATA UIT CACHE")
    
    let request = UserCore.fetchUserDataRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "points", ascending: false)]
    
    if leaderboardType == .getFriendsLeaderboard {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friendsLeaderboard == true")
    }
    else {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "competitionLeaderboard == true")
    }
    
    do {
        let users = try self.viewContext!.fetch(request)
        
        for user in users {
            var newUser = User()
            
            if leaderboardType == .getFriendsLeaderboard {
                (newUser.identifier, newUser.points, newUser.friendsLeaderboard) = (user.identifier, Int(user.points), true)
            }
            else {
                (newUser.identifier, newUser.points, newUser.competitionLeaderboard) = (user.identifier, Int(user.points), true)
            }
            
            self.leaderboardResult.append(newUser)
        }
        
        return true
    }
    catch {
        return false
    }

}
```

The save function is as follows:

```
func saveCachedUserInformation(leaderboardType: APIRequest) {

    print("SAVEN VAN DATA UIT CACHE")

    do {
        
        for user in self.leaderboardResult {
        
                let newUser = UserCore(context: viewContext!)
                
                if leaderboardType == .getFriendsLeaderboard {
                    (newUser.identifier, newUser.points, newUser.friendsLeaderboard) = (user.identifier, Int64(user.points!), true)
                }
                else {
                    (newUser.identifier, newUser.points, newUser.competitionLeaderboard) = (user.identifier, Int64(user.points!), true)
                }
        }
            
        try self.viewContext?.save()
    }
    catch {}

}
```

Comment: `let newUser = UserCore(context: viewContext!)`, you are always creating a new instance. If you want to update instead then you need to have some logic to check if the object exists.

Comment: I actually disagree with you, since `viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` handles these cases. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergebypropertystoretrumpmergepolicy

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do you know a better solution for the update logic other than checking for each user in the array if it is already in CoreData?

Comment: I haven’t used merging but I think you have misunderstood what it is, I believe it is for merging data between threads/context and not between new and existing objects in the same context.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hmm okay, do you know a better solution for the update logic other than checking for each user in the array if it is already in CoreData?